# How to compare metrics in graph? MetricsReloaded

Tags: java, intellij-idea, metrics

Does anyone know if it's possible to compare two different metrics using MetricsReloaded in IntelliJ?

For example I would like to have a distribution graph comparing cyclomatic complexity and lines of code?

It may not be possible, if no I will simply export the data.

Comment: I have put the MetricsReloaded in plugins folder of InteliJ? How to enable the plugin in the project?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible using MetricsReloaded. You might want to submit a feature request here: https://github.com/BasLeijdekkers/MetricsReloaded/issues